# apache airflow define data for all scripts in DAG folder

Tags: airflow

I have data like Amazon S3 connection settings etc.. which is relevant for many of the .py files in my DAG folder.

I'm aware that `default_args` is shared with all DAGS in a specific .py file
My question is how can I define data which will be accessible for **ALL** .py files on my DAG folder?

Imagine that I need to change my S3 connection details... I don't want to go over all files and change it one by one. I want to change it just in one place.

Does Airflow support this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is precisely the use case for the `Connection` model. Instead of passing around sensitive information, namely credentials, you create a `Connection` record which holds that information on your behalf and which you reference with a string.

You can [read more about them here](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#connections).

Comment: It even encrypts the password!

Comment: What if it's not connections? This was just and example. Say I'm using a VAT value for calculations in many DAGs (in different .py files). Now the VAT is 18%. tomorrow it can be 19%... I don't want to hard codded it in each process... I want to reference it from each process and change it only in one place.

Comment: You can use a `Variable` for that.